# running typescript code using import() from command line

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I am trying to create a command line utility for a project I have made in TypeScript.
The code dynamically imports some typescript modules from a designated folder.
It seems that the imports in those modules are not resolved for some reasons.
In the below run `contracts/CheckContract.ts` is dynamically imported, and it tries to import `src/check/Check`, which fails.

The exact same code runs fine from a jest unit test.

The project is at https://github.com/kode-konveyor/cdd-ts/tree/6d7c18543b2de5f38f8e553fb76df4b6aebf2afc

What should I do to make it run from command line?

```
mag@mag-Librem-15-v4:~/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts$ ts-node src/index.ts 
running contracts
Error: Cannot find module 'src/check/Check'
Require stack:
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/contracts/CheckContract.ts
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runContractsfromList.ts
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runAllContracts.ts
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/contracts/CheckContract.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/contracts/CheckContract.ts',
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runContractsfromList.ts',
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runAllContracts.ts',
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/index.ts'
  ]
}
mag@mag-Librem-15-v4:~/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts$ ls dist/out-tsc/src/check/Check.*
dist/out-tsc/src/check/Check.js  dist/out-tsc/src/check/Check.js.map
mag@mag-Librem-15-v4:~/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts$ ls src/check/Check
CheckReturnValue.ts  Check.ts             
mag@mag-Librem-15-v4:~/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts$ ls src/check/Check.ts 
src/check/Check.ts
mag@mag-Librem-15-v4:~/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts$ ts-node --esm src/index.ts 
running contracts
Error: Cannot find module 'src/check/Check'
Require stack:
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/contracts/CheckContract.ts
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runContractsfromList.ts
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runAllContracts.ts
- /home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/contracts/CheckContract.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/contracts/CheckContract.ts',
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runContractsfromList.ts',
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/runAllContracts.ts',
    '/home/mag/project/KodeKonveyor/cdd-ts/src/index.ts'
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts",
    "contracts/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cdd-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test-time Contract Development framework for TypeScript",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "qa": "npm run lint &&npm run test&& npm run mutate",
    "mutate": "stryker run",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@stryker-mutator/jest-runner": "^6.4.1",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
    "fast-glob": "^3.2.12",
    "jest-mock": "^29.4.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "tsyringe": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.4.3",
    "@stryker-mutator/core": "^6.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^24.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "jest-mock-extended": "^3.0.3",
    "stryker-cli": "^1.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.8",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Use file extension, i.e. `src/check/Check.js`.

Comment: I believe that a mature software ecosystem should know better than that.
And anyways:
contracts/CheckContract.ts:1:23 - error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing 'src/check/Check' instead.